# Error in Javascript when using Spring to output data into arrays

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp

I am having an issue with using Spring's  mechanism to fill in an array of strings if one of the strings contain a new line.

The jsp code looks like this:

```
function foo() {
    var strs = new Array();
    <c:forEach items"${strItems}" var="s">
        strs.push("${s}");
    </c:forEach>
}
```

After being rendered for the client, the javascript becomes:

```
function foo() {
    var strs = new Array();
        strs.push("item1");
        strs.push("item2
with
newlines
in it.");
        strs.push("item3");
}
```

Which is now invalid javascript.  I need to keep the endlines in the string, so I cannot scrub the data of them.  I am unsure of what to do, any suggestions would be a big help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are libs to do the type conversion:

- [json-simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/)
- [gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

And all you have to do is to let them serialize your array, and output the result as a string.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  No fuss, no muss.

I ended up just doing the escape example:
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
public String getSafeString() {
    return JSONObject.escape(myString);
}
...

Comment: Why not use `JSONValue.toJSONString(list)`? It's way more neat, and possibly faster.